# Count words in relative columns and/or rows of a Google Sheet with argument placeholders

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to get the word count of a cell in a column and/or row relative to the current cell of a Google Sheet. Furthermore, I want to make this a reusable function by incorporating argument placeholders. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish this, there are three components: finding relative cells, counting the words, and handling empty cells.

To find relative cells, we want to use the `INDIRECT(cell_reference_as_string, [is_A1_notation])` function, which converts text Strings into cell or range references. `cell_reference_as_string` is expecting a text String enclosed with quotation marks. `is_A1_notation` is an optional Boolean parameter specifying A1 notation (default) or R1C1 notation. Read more [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en).

In our case, we will be using R1C1 notation, so `is_A1_notation` will be set to `False`.
R1C1 notation can give absolute and relative cell references. Here are examples of each:

- `"R1C1"` is an absolute reference to the `(1,1)` cell of the sheet. Therefore `"R2C1"` would be `(2,1)`, and `"R1C2"` would be `(1,2)`, etc...
- Using square brackets to enclose the numerals creates a relative reference. `"R[1]C[1]"` is a relative reference from the current cell to one row down and one column right. Relative references can also be negative, with `"R[-1]C[-1]"` referencing the cell one row up and one column left to the current cell. Keep in mind that a negative relative reference from the left most column or top row will cause the reference to wrap to the right most column or bottom row.
- Not incorporating numerals will have the notation specify the current row and/or column. `RC` specifies the current cell, whereas `RC[1]` specifies the current row, one column to the right, etc...

One could assume that `cell_reference_as_string` would be `"R[x]C[y]`, where `x` and `y` are argument placeholders for relative row and column. However, this won't work, as we can't add a variable to a String like that. The variable needs to be concatenated to the String after its value is looked up, which we can do with the operator `&`. The value of `cell_reference_as_string` is therefore `"R["&x&"]C["&y&"]"`

Putting this all together and we have the formula `INDIRECT("R["&x&"]C["&y&"]",FALSE)`

From here, it gets a lot simpler. We need to count the words in the cell, which can be done with the `COUNTA(value1, [value2, ...])` function. `value1` is a value or range to be counted, with `value2, ...` being optional parameters for additional counting. Read more [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093991?hl=en).

To count words specifically, we will want to make the String of words into an array by splitting across empty spaces. This can be done with the `SPLIT(text, delimiter, [split_by_each], [remove_empty_text])` function. `text` is the formula we created above, `INDIRECT("R["&x&"]C["&y&"]",FALSE)`. `delimiter` is what we want to split on, which is `" "`. We don't need the two optional parameters, although you can read more about them [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en).

Combining what we have so far, the function is `COUNTA(SPLIT(INDIRECT("R["&x&"]C["&y&"]",FALSE)," "))`. This will return the word count for relative cell `current + (x,y)`. The last component is to handle empty cells, such that the whitespace in them doesn't evaluate to a count of 1.

This can be accomplished by using the `IF(logical_expression, value_if_true, value_if_false)`  function. `logical_expression` is an expression that evaluates to `True` or `False`. `value_if_true` is the value to return if that expression is `True`. `value_if_false` is the value to return if that expression is `False`. Read more [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en).

The next step is to convert the `INDIRECT` function result into a boolean expression. We can do this by appending `=""` to the function: `INDIRECT("R["&x&"]C["&y&"]",FALSE)=""`. This is the `logical_expression` parameter. Since we are checking if the text is an empty string, we can assign the `value_if_true` to zero, and the `value_if_false` to the result of the function `COUNTA(SPLIT(INDIRECT("R["&x&"]C["&y&"]",FALSE)," "))`.

Wrapping the formula in this will create the final function, which is `=IF(INDIRECT("R["&x&"]C["&y&"]",FALSE)="",0,COUNTA(SPLIT(INDIRECT("R["&x&"]C["&y&"]",FALSE)," ")))`, with argument placeholders `x` for row and `y` for column.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can try:

```
=LET(row_offset,-1,
     col_offset,1,
     COUNTA(IFERROR(SPLIT(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()+row_offset,COLUMN()+col_offset))," "))))
```

Where `row_offset` and `col_offset` are the row and column offset relative to the cell in which you enter the formula. They cannot both be zero or it will result in a circular dependency error.

To make it a function, create a Named Function with the following arguments:

- row_offset
- col_offset

And the following formula definition:

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(SPLIT(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()+row_offset,COLUMN()+col_offset))," ")))
```